# Pre - compactness on $
{C}\left[{0,1}\right]
$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

we say that the set is pre-compact if its closure is compact .

how can we use that to Show if the following sete  are pre- compact on 
$
{C}\left[{0,1}\right]
$
:

a) $
{x}_{n}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{t}^{{n}\hspace{0.33em}}{\mathrm{,}}{n}\mathrm{\in}{N}
$

b) $
{x}_{n}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\sin{nt}{\mathrm{,}}{n}\mathrm{\in}{N}
$

c) $
{x}_{n}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\sin{nt}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{,}}\hspace{0.33em}{n}\mathrm{\in}\left[{1\mathrm{,}2}\right]
$

d) $
{x}_{n}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{e}^{{t}\mathrm{{-}}{n}}{\mathrm{,}}\hspace{0.33em}{n}\mathrm{\in}{R}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{,}}{n}\mathrm{\geq}{0}
$

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: Perhaps the point here is that in these simple cases you can solve it directly from the definition, without using a big theorem like Arzela-Ascoli.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prahlad Vaidyanathan has suggested, we are going to use the Arzel-Ascoli theorem. From that theorem, we know that, given a subset $\mathbf{F}\subset \mathcal{C}[0,1]$, we know it's pre-compact (in the topology induced by the uniform norm), if and only if:

- for all $t\in[0,1],\forall\epsilon>0,\exists \delta \mbox{ such that }\forall x_n\in\mathbf{F},|t-s|<\delta\implies |x_n(t)-x_n(s)|<\epsilon$;
- for all $t\in[0,1]$, $\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\{|x_n(t)|:x_n\in\mathbf{F}\}<\infty$.

a). The functions are definitely bounded in $[0,1]$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so the second condition holds. However, the first one doesn't. Choose $t=1$ and $\epsilon=.5$. Then, for any $\delta$, you can choose $n=\lceil\log_{1-\delta/2}(.5)\rceil$ and $s=1-\delta/2$, and then you'll have $|s-t|<\delta$ and $|s^n-t^n|>\epsilon$.

b) The functions are all bounded by $1$. However, the first condition fails. Indeed, choose $t=0$ and $\epsilon=.01$. Then for any $\delta$, you can choose an $n$ such that it's the closest integer to $\frac{\sin^{-1}(1)}{\delta/2}+\frac{k\pi}{\delta}$ for some integer $k$ and $s=\frac{\delta}{2}$ and you'll have $|s-t|<\delta$ and $|\sin(ns)-\sin(nt)|>\epsilon$.

c) The functions are all bounded by $1$. Between $t$ and $t+\delta$, $\sin(2t)$ has a variation bounded by $\frac{4}{\pi}\delta$. The variation of $\sin(t)$ on the same interval is bounded by $\frac{2}{\pi}\delta$. So, for a given $\epsilon$, if we choose $\delta=\frac{\pi}{4}\epsilon$, we can rest assured that when
$$|t-s|<\delta$$
we will have
$$|\sin(2t)-\sin(2s)|$$
and similarly for all the $\sin(nt)$'s with $n$ between $1$ and $2$.

d) These functions are bounded by $e$. As $n$ increases, the total variation in that interval decreases, so we can use an argument similar to the one above to conclude that the set is pre-compact.

So a) and b) are not pre-compact, but c) and d) are.